# IMAP Bounced Email : Original message is removed from bounced email

Tags: java, imap, apache-camel-mail

IMAP is removing the original content from the mail, as can be seen from below example (The original message has been removed from the bounce message.)

Question: Is there any config that I can provide to IMAP while connecting to always send the original message?

Example :

```
Return-Path: <>
To: a@ba.com
From: Mail Administrator <postmaster@b.com>
Reply-To: <Postmaster@b.com>
Subject: Mail System Error - Returned Mail with Subject: Hi from a
Date: Tue, 11 Oct 2018 12:38:19
Message-ID: <12121213312.AH12R3177.ns12d12121231u2fep03t-svc.1.q.com@qwp03t-q>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/report;
        report-type=delivery-status;
        Boundary="===========================_ _= 8483766(3177)q"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit


--===========================_ _= 8483766(3177)q
Content-Type: text/plain

This Message was undeliverable due to the following reason:

Each of the following recipients was rejected by a remote mail server.
The reasons given by the server are included to help you determine why
each recipient was rejected.

    Recipient: <a12312121@gmail.com>
    Reason:    5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try               5.1.1 double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or               5.1.1 unnecessary spaces. Learn more at               5.1.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=NoSuchUser w02-q2.2a60 - gsmtp


Please reply to <Postmaster@a.b.com>
if you feel this message to be in error.

The original message has been removed from the bounce message.

--===========================_ _= 8483766(3177)q
Content-Type: message/delivery-status

Reporting-MTA: dns; asasd.as.aas.a.a.com
Arrival-Date: Tue, 11 Oct 2018 12:38:06
Received-From-MTA: dns; a.a.a.a.b.com

Action: failed
Status: 5.1.1
Remote-MTA: dns; gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com (172.217.194.27)
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try
 550-5.1.1 double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or
 550-5.1.1 unnecessary spaces. Learn more at
 550 5.1.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=NoSuchUser w20-v6si34204854plp.260 - gsmtp

--===========================_ _= 8483766(3177)q--
```

Comment: I'll vote to close; this isn't about IMAP at all, but rather about some unnamed software. It might be worth posting on serverfault (but naming the software and not dragging in unrelated stuff).

Answer (score 0):

IMAP - internet message access protocol is a protocol to access emails on a mail server. This does not dictate what is provided by the server when an Email is requested via IMAP. I would suggest posting the mail server you are running as there may be configuration settings on the mail server that can do this.

Comment: The mail server is MX9.